# Word hyphenation feature is not available

Tags: microsoft-office-2016, microsoft-word-2016

When opening a Document in Word 2016, I always get the following error message

> Word hyphenation feature is not available. Run the Microsoft Office Setup program, install this feature an then try again

[image]

But there is no such option to add the feature in the Office 2016 Setup?

**How can I add this feature to Word in Office 2016?**

Comment: [This](http://www.sevenforums.com/microsoft-office/74308-disable-forever-word-hyphenation-feature-not-avai.html) should still apply.  Additionally "In Office 2007, 2010 and 2013 go to Page Layout tab, then click "Hyphenation" and select "None" then save the document.
You will have to do this each time opening a new one again."  this also still applies to Office 2016.  The problem is unique to the document and the language of the text within it.  My guess you need to install a language pack.  You can also try [this](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=44310).

Comment: Is the document set to use a language that isn't installed? Hyphenation dictionaries apply to particular languages.

Answer (score 2):

- Open Word Document
- You will received the error message popup --> for this last time click on OK
- Click on Page Layout
- Under Page Setup --> Click on Hyphenation
- Click on Hyphenation Options --> popup menu appears
- Uncheck the checkbox for 'Automatically hyphenate document'
- Uncheck the checkbox for 'Hyphenate words in CAPS'
- Click on OK button
- Save the word doc
- Close it
- Open the Word Doc again, the error message won't popup.

DONE!

Comment: This is about "how to turn off this feature for specific document ", not "how to install it and make it work".

Comment: The question even states that he wants to enable it.

Answer (score 2):

I just had this issue and it was due to not having the proofing tools installed for a language used in the document.

For Office 2016 on Windows 10, installing the language from the system settings did not install the proofing tools, but the following worked:

- Go to https://support.office.com/en-us/article/language-accessory-pack-for-office-82ee1236-0f9a-45ee-9c72-05b026ee809f
- Select the language for the proofing tools you need in the drop-down.
- Download and install the language pack

Comment: worked. thank you

Comment: This only works for Windows. In the case of Mac there is nothing to be installed, it's just that some languages don't have support for hyphenation, like Finnish.

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/proofing-tools-available-in-office-for-mac-e175007d-193d-4efc-afce-5e27a59f1057?ui=en-us&rs=en-us&ad=us