# How can I turn Word 2016 hypenation ON?

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-office, language, microsoft-office-2016, localization

[This question](https://superuser.com/questions/980035/word-hyphenation-feature-is-not-available) is a question that asks how to turn hyphenation ON, and the comment and downvoted answer both say, "Here's what you need to do to turn hyphenation OFF."

What I've gathered is that hyphenation is something that you're supposed to turn on in Office Setup. However, Office Setup as I have been able to access it now doesn't appear to offer any choices (other than continuing in the process). It's not a multistep setup wizard that obviously lets you choose between typical and custom installations and choose complete installations.

So, a couple of questions:

1. Is the correct tool Office Setup or something else?
2. Is there UI, perhaps not visually highlighted, that can be used to turn on this feature?
3. As, in my case, the user wants to have hyphenation working in Russian as well as English, what do I need to install so that text in both languages is hyphenated? Do I install a language pack, or a hyphenation dictionary, or something else?

Thanks,

Comment: I believe what you failed to grasp about the linked question is that it was regarding an error based on document corruption, not a feature-addition in Word. Ramhound's comment is the correct solution. Hyphenation is a part of the proofing tools. To "install" it you select the Proofing Tools for the language(s) you need in the Office installer. This information is from the article linked in Ramhound's comment.